# URL-routing in Magento: how to get rid of index.php from URL

Tags: magento, url, url-routing

I am developing a website on Magento and 90% has been developed. But URL structure is not proper there.

Current URLs structure is like:

> http://abcd.com/index.php/aa-bb.html

But I want them to be routed like:

> http://abcd.com/aa-bb.html.

How can the URL routing/mapping be updated?

Deepak

Comment: Your both urls are same. http://abcd.com/index.php/aa-bb.html. Please Edit your question and ask it properly

Comment: "But url structure is not proper there." Where?

Comment: Hi Karan, I have edited my question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

credits : @Arslan Hashim for [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/remove-index-php-from-the-magento-url-gives-404-error)

To remove `index.php` from URLs follow the below steps :

1. Log-in Magento Admin
2. Go to `System -> Configuration -> Web`
3. From *Search Engine Optimisation* tab **Use Web Server Rewrites** select **YES**.
4. Make sure your *Secure* and *Unsecure* base urls should end with **“/”**.
5. Now edit your `.htaccess` ( will be in magento root folder ) and paste the code which is given at **[this link][1]**